# How to force placement of controls in superclass form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

*For a fast summary of the problem look at the picture at the bottom.*

Hello,

I created a `Form` (named BaseForm) that serves as base for all my windows.
This base-Form contains (for the sake of simplicity) something like a "statusbar" (a usercontrol) at the bottom.

That statusbar is Locked so it can't be moved or resized in the designer.
It also has the it's anchor set to left,bottom,right so it always stays at the bottom and resizes horizontally.

Now when make another `Form` and change so it inherits MyProject.BaseForm instead of System.Windows.Forms.Form, the statusbar is there.

But now there is a problem with the statusbars position and size.
The statusbars standard location and size is wrong. VisualStudio takes the location and size from the BaseForm instead of applying the Anchor.

Also I can't (and don't want to!) move/resize the statusbar to fix the problem.

One obvious and working solution would be setting the statusbars Dock property to Bottom.
But I can't use that as a generic solution to my problem because I also have controls that should not be docked. (For example a button that should always stay at the bottom-right corner of the form)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is to use a `TableLayoutPanel` instead of explicit docking.  Create a 2 row `TableLayoutPanel` in the parent form.  Make the bottom row `AutoSize` and put the status bar into that.  This way the derived forms are free to add content in the other row which represents the remainder of the control.

Comment: A nice idea, but even if you set the `TableLayoutPanel`s Modifier to "public" you cannot place controls into it when you are in Form2.

Comment: @Felheart why not?  It's been years since I did heavy WinForms work but I remember designing controls in this exact fashion

Comment: You always get the "not allowed" cursor when trying to drag a control into an inherited TableLayoutPanel. Even if the inherited control has Locked=false and Modifiers=public. This only seems to work with Panels and only if they're marked as "public" (which I also try to avoid)

Comment: @Felheart why not just add a panel into the `TableLayoutPanel` top row and then make that particular panel Public as well?

Comment: @Felheart note that what you are trying to achieve is not always possible.  The WinForms designer is geared towards non-inheritted controls.  Once you introduce inheritance it gets much harder to get the experience you want.  I spent a lot of time trying to work around this (and eventually just got good at hand coding my forms).

Comment: I already tried to place a Panel inside the TableLayoutPanel, everything marked Public, but it doesn't work. Maybe I really have to move/resize them myself everytime...

Comment: Since all the spots where my usercontrols need to go are either a side or a corner of the form, I used multiple TableLayoutPanels to build some sort of "frame" around the BaseForm. Now the controls are always placed and stretched correctly, while allowing me to place controls in the center of the derived form! Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple problem, the control is private so can't be messed with in the derived form.  None of its properties are accessible, including Location and Size.  Which freezes it solid in the wrong spot on your derived form.  The layout engine can't move it either.  And why it displays the lock icon.

Go back to the BaseForm, select the user control and change the Modifiers property from Private to Protected.  Rebuild.  Now you can move it on the derived form where it needs to go.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I have many forms that inherit from BaseForm so the idea is that I don't have to manually correct the position of the control (acutally multiple controls) everytime. I actually want them locked. I solved it by carefully using TableLayoutPanels.